# AutoFs with specific user´s permissions

Tags: permissions, autofs, ownership

I have autofs working properly. I can mount a Windows share on Linux server without problems.

But there is one issue: I don't want that mounted share to be public to all Linux users, just for a small group or a unique user.

- The auto.master file:
   `/mnt    /etc/auto.cifs   --timeout=60 --ghost`
- The auto.cifs file:
  `MountedPoint -fstype=cifs,username=JohnDoe,password=password,uid=108956,gid=540,forceuid,forcegid ://server.com/share$`
- `autofs` is mounting the shares at `/mnt/MountedPoint` but with the permissions

  ```
  dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root
  ```
- I tried `chmod 700` but I got:

  ```
  chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/MountedPoint/’: Permission denied
  ```
- Also tried `chown userid:gid /mnt/MountedPoint/` and got the 'permission denied' message.

Is there any way to configure AutoFs to mount a windows share which can be accessed only by a specific user other than root?

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux version 7.9